# How to change cookie name

Tags: cookies

Im trying to figure out how can I change names to cookies that wordpress is setting for example on login.

```
wordpress_test_cookie = sitename_test_cookie
```

or/ and

```
 wordpress_logged_in = sitename_test_cookie
```

Comment: Any specific reason for this?

Comment: in my case, I have to install another wordpress instance in the subdirectory. i don't want to create a conflict in the login instances

Answer (score 8):

Check out the [`wp_cookie_constants()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_cookie_constants/) and [`ms_cookie_constants()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/ms_cookie_constants/) functions, to see available cookies.

We can try this in the `wp-config.php` file:

```
// Here we just simulate how it's done in the core
define( 'COOKIEHASH',           md5( 'http://example.tld' )    ); 

// Then we override the cookie names:
define( 'USER_COOKIE',          'wpse_user_'      . COOKIEHASH );
define( 'PASS_COOKIE',          'wpse_pass_'      . COOKIEHASH );
define( 'AUTH_COOKIE',          'wpse_'           . COOKIEHASH );
define( 'SECURE_AUTH_COOKIE',   'wpse_sec_'       . COOKIEHASH );
define( 'LOGGED_IN_COOKIE',     'wpse_logged_in_' . COOKIEHASH );
define( 'TEST_COOKIE',          'wpse_test_cookie'             );
```

or using PHP 5.6+ :

```
// Then we override the cookie names:
const USER_COOKIE        = 'wpse_user_'      . COOKIEHASH;
const PASS_COOKIE        = 'wpse_pass_'      . COOKIEHASH;
const AUTH_COOKIE        = 'wpse_'           . COOKIEHASH;
const SECURE_AUTH_COOKIE = 'wpse_sec_'       . COOKIEHASH;
const LOGGED_IN_COOKIE   = 'wpse_logged_in_' . COOKIEHASH;
const TEST_COOKIE        = 'wpse_test_cookie';
```

where we must adjust the site url `http://example.tld` to our needs.

But I also wonder, as @PieterGoosen, why you need to change it.

Comment: Why change it. To hide traces of wordpress for security reasons.

Comment: I was hoping that the OP would explain better his needs and reasons. I looked into this out of  "theoretical" curiosity ;-) In general I don't think this makes any difference on HTTP connections and one should aim for HTTPS encryption to avoid e.g. network sniffing. But I'm not a security expert ;-)  @wpstudent

Comment: Another reason to change it... two installations can potentially have a conflict in the login (cannot be logged into both at once in the same browser instance). This solves that!

Comment: thanks for commenting and mentioning an usage case @groovenectar

Answer (score 2):

To add to the comments... another reason for changing the test cookie in particular is to block bad logins. Ripped straight outta the always excellent ask apache...

http://www.askapache.com/security/stop-wordpress-exploits-spam/#Block_Logins_bad_cookie

**Block Logins with bad cookie**

You should all be using a custom login cookie name definable with constants in your wp-config.php file. That means the default cookie wordpress_test_cookie will never be set, so you can block bots that use this default!

The way to deviate from the default is to set this constant to anything you want in your wp-config.php

```
define( 'TEST_COOKIE', 'use_this_cookie_name_instead_of_wordpress_test_cookie' );
```

**Block bad test cookies**

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^POST.*wp-login [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} "wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check" [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]'
```