# How are sites using wordpress hiding wordpress cookies that have "wp" or "wordpress" in the cookie name?

Tags: cookies

I have looked at some big sites that are running wordpress and not one mention of it in their cookies I am trying to do that with my site...

Comment: What do you mean? WP doesn't set any cookies for visitors.

Comment: What is wp-settings-1, wp-settings-time-1, wordpress_test_cookie then?

Comment: Where do they come from? As a normal visitor, they should not be set. Maybe from comments? Or when you log in?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change cookie name](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/202009/how-to-change-cookie-name)

Comment: wordpress_test_cookie is only set if you open the login page, and the other two only when you log in (the 1 in both is your user ID)

Comment: I tried that kero and it didnt seem to work

Comment: Even when I log in on big sites that use wordpress there is no mention of wordpress anywhere in their cookies